# Setting dijit NumberSpinner value programmatically

Tags: javascript, dojo, set, dijit.form

I would like to change the `dijit/form/NumberSpinner` value programmatically.  How to achieve this using a '`data-dojo-attach-point`' or `id`?

The below code update the Number Spinner text, but it gives me

> "Uncaught TypeError: c.advice.apply is not a function" error.

How to properly change the value programmatically?

```
this.typeResidential.set('value', 30);
```

Comment: @bRIMOs Thank you so much for your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are writing your app ,
if you are writing a widget both using `data-dojo-attach-point` and access this.your-attach-name Or using `id` and accessing widget throw `registry` .

bellow example by using an `id` and set the value of the spiiner using `dijit/registry` of this widget by using `registry.by("widgetId").set("value",val);`

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/9rLtzm1u/

```js
require(["dijit/registry","dojo/ready","dojo/parser"],
  function(registry,ready,parser){
        parser.parse();
      ready(function(){
         registry.byId("typeResidential").set("value",213);
        });    
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="typeResidential"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since 'data-dojo-attach-point' didn't work for me, I tried your suggestion 'registry'.  But, I still get the same error.

Comment: could you please post the code you're working on to have a better visiblilty

Comment: the error was from another function that shares the same  'data-dojo-attach-point'.  Though, I learned using 'registry' to set the value in the dijit widget.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Great :) , So please if that help mark the answer as resolved **✓** (left the answer ) ( like in this image =>[image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you

Answer (score 1):

In dojo you can set properties for a widget programmatically (as properly showed by bRIMOs answer) or declaratively.

When using programmatically make sure that the `this` has the right scope to your widget.

```
this.typeResidential.set('value', 30);
```

In alternative, below an example of a declarative syntax, which consist in adding in your HTML markup a property of name `value`.

You can achieve the same result in both ways, it really depends of you application design.

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner"]);
```

```html
<script>
var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug: true,
    };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner"
        id="integerspinner2"
        value="1000"
        data-dojo-props="smallDelta:10, constraints:{min:9,max:1550,places:0}"
        name="someNumber"
        />
</div>
```

Comment: my pleasure :). ++

Comment: @GibboK It seems I am correctly setting the value.  I used the same method for 'dijit/form/HorizontalSlider' and work without any problem.  I wonder why I am getting the error message when I try to set the value for   'dijit/form/NumberSpinner'.  I made sure 'this' is in scope.

Comment: @Mackey please post a working example of code where you reproduce the error and we will have a look :) Unfortunately without seeing the code we cannot really debug error related to c.advice.apply

Comment: @GibboK  I found out that the error is coming from another function that is related to the same 'data-dojo-attach-point'.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Mackey You are welcome. Please consider accepting or up-voting an answer using the TICK/UP icons on its left side. Thanks and happy coding :)